# Using tuples in a linked list in python

Tags: python, linked-list

My teacher wants us to recreate the dict class in Python using tuples and linkedlists (for collisions). One of the methods is used to return a value given a key. I know how to do this in a tuple ( find the key at location[0] and return location[1]) but I have no idea how I would do this in the case of a collision. Any suggestions? If more info is needed please let me know

Comment: Do you have to implement your own linked list, or are you using Python's list type?
You usually worry about collisions when using a hash algorithm to map arbitrary string keys to an easily-sortable value.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have some sort of hash to get a shortlist of possibilities, so, you hash your key to a small-ish number, e.g. 0-256 (as an example, it might hash to 63). You can then go directly to your data at index 63. Because you might have more than one item that hashes to 63, your entry for 63 will contain a list of (key,value) pairs, that you would have to search one by one - effectively, you've reduced your search area by 255/256th of the full list. Optionally, when the collisions for a particular key exceeds a threshold, you could repeat the process - so you get mydict[63][92], again reducing the problem size by the same factor. You could repeat this indefinitely.